# Why use Collection.allow instead of just Meteor.methods and Meteor.call to those methods?

Tags: collections, meteor

Running through the basic Parties Meteor example (http://meteor.com/examples/parties),

I am wondering why you would need to ever use Collection.allow to specify which inserts,updates,etc... go through instead of just using Meteor.methods and then issue Meteor.call from the client.

Seems that the "methods" way is always better since its more flexible (i.e custom functions)

Answer (score 8):

The allow and deny interface is flexible enough for most access control that you would want.  If you can use the built-ins, you end up with cleaner, more understandable, more readable code.  It's also more Meteoric, in that it preserves Meteor's "database-everywhere" abstraction of being able to perform database operations directly on the client.

It's possible to deny all operations on your collections and then only expose access to the collections through methods.  But there's a good chance you'd end up re-implementing a CRUD interface anyway, and you'd probably end up re-implementing the allow and deny functions.

I try to only use Meteor.methods if I find it difficult to express the access control I need through the allow and deny interface.  For example, there are times when you need to update two related collections at once and the validation needs to examine the proposed changes to both collections before determining if the operation should proceed.  That's cleaner with a Meteor.method.

Comment: So basically, `"simple crud for free"` = `collection.allow`, `"slightly more complex model/authorization logic starts creeping in"` = `Meteor.method`?

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaking Collection.allow purpose : it's used to restrict what operation can be performed on your collection by the **client-side** code. These restrictions are not applied server-side. And you are indeed supposed to execute write operations on your collection in your Meteor.methods, and then call them from the client code.

Collection.allow is here to prevent the end-user and potentially hacker from being able to do what ever sweets his taste with your data. Never forget that your client side code can be tempered with.

In the example you mentioned, suppose that you have another field in your Party structure. You may not want me to be able to update this field. Without the "update" callback test on fields name in Parties, I would be able to inject a change in that field.

Get the point?

Comment: If I don't setup any "allow" 's then all database access is denyed anyways though, right? So what's the point?

Comment: It's up to you to decide if you want to allow direct insert/update/delete call on the collection from your client code. If you don't want to allow that, don't set "allow" up. If however you want to be able to execute direct operation on your collection, you **should** set it up and triple-check the data you get in the callbacks

Comment: So just to be safe and consistent, I can just run everything through methods and validate the data there, eliminating the need for allows.

Comment: yes, you can. make sure to disable insecure mode in this case (see last paragraph in the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#allow

Comment: you can do it through methods, but allows make the client side code far easier and it can take care of validation too, its also easier to maintain as one validation rule handles all client requests. In a method you have to customize it for each call